# execute .then() in a return promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

My code is:-

```
function scammer(message) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        if(condition){
            if (condition) {
                bot.KickMember(params).then((message)=>{
                    console.log("kicked");
                });
            } else {
                console.log("Not kicked");
            }
            resolve();
       }else{
          reject();
       }
   });
}
```

In the above code, function scammer works perfectly also the if-else statement but the then() does not work since I put it into a new promise, is there a way to execute then() without getting it out of the new promise.

Comment: Your `then` function will be invoked when the promise you got from `bot.KickMember(params)` will be resolved. What's the problem with that?

Comment: It's not clear what *is there a way to execute then() without getting it out of the new promise*  means?

Comment: **I think** you just want to return the promise, `return bot.KickMember(params).then((message) => {` but that's a guess as I don't really understand your question

Comment: This is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: `resolve();` should be inside `bot.KickMember(params).then((message) => {`. otherwise promise will resolved before bot library do his work.

Comment: @HardikShahEdited the code

Comment: Please edit correctly. Your code is currently messed up. Can not find anything promising. may be correct indentation.

Comment: Still, I would like to point out that your `resolve();` will resolve promises before bot work done. You should put `resolve()` inside `bot.KickMember(params).then((message)=>{`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create a promise, just return the one you got:

```
if (condition) {
    return bot.KickMember(params).then((message) => {
        console.log("kicked");
    });
} else {
    console.log("Not kicked");
    return Promise.reject(new Error("some reason"));
}
```

Comment: I just edited the code, I need to return resolve on the execution of if and reject on the execution of reject

Comment: @JonasW. oh I didn't realize that `reject()` was an edit, now your initial answer makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

Probably like this: `resolve()` should inside the `bot` promise.

```
function scammer(message) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        if (condition) {
            bot.KickMember(params).then((message)=>{
                console.log("kicked");
                resolve();
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Not kicked");
            reject();
        }
    });
}
```

As per your code `resolve()` will execute before you land inside `then` of `bot` promise.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I removed the resolve() and reject() but still it doesn't work